# mysql Access denied for user 'root'@'name of the computer' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database

I am getting this error everytime im trying to connect to my database

```
    Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): 
Access denied for user 'root'@'name of the computer' (using password: YES) in PATH_TO_FILE on line 8
```

I checked the privilege and that's what I got

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

with that command

```
show GRANTS for "root"@"127.0.0.1"
```

Furthermore this is how i connect

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('path to server', 'root', 'gourami',"recherche");
```

but as you can see the name of the user is not the same in the error message...

I have no idea what is going on, because that should normally work..

I wonder if its my host that is blocked but I had that problem before,but the message wasn't the same. I fixed it with the command.

```
flush hosts;
```

But this time it didn't work

Comment: Check the "Related" sidebar to the right. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw?rq=1

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli_...

Comment: He is using mysqli. . .

Answer (score 4):

There shouldn't be a port number in the permissions, it's just `user@host`. Change the grant to:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to root@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: And don't forget to execute 'flush privileges' afterwards.

Comment: Does the error message actually say `*USER*`, not `root`? Then you need to add permissions for that username, not root.

Comment: Actually its says 'root'@'name of the computer'

Comment: Then grant to `root@hostname` instead of 127.0.0.1. MySQL is actually very picky about this, and allows you to set different privileges based on where a user is connecting from. As such always use the exact same identification as he puts in the error, or wildcard to all of them.